# Shapeshift + bitcoin cash question. The deposit link expired before the deposit reached it

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-cash, shapeshift.io

At first, the transaction stayed unconfirmed, and then, four hours later, it had one confirmation, and now, two days later, the blockexplorer says it has 247 (?) confirmations, but the wallet still says it has two and is pending.  I figured that when the amount will reach Shapeshift, they will issue an automatic refund although the blockchair says that the main part of the deposit is already sent and spent. I tried to use CPFP while it was still unconfirmed to draft the funds back, but it seems like I misunderstood the function. Can anybody tell me what's the problem, if it's stuck for centuries or how to speed it up? And it is actually a second time in a row I get into this situation. Anyway, would anybody just sort out my confusion?
41cd7bb49bab97d82063f5fde1b2e5b9e8cb2cbc1faba65a938d70c69dbce8a7

Comment: What is "the wallet" in your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See also [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

> the blockexplorer says it has 247 (?) confirmations, but the wallet still says it has two and is pending.

Sounds like an issue with the wallet not an issue with the transaction. Indeed, the transaction has many confirmations now, contact the support for the wallet you are using to see what the issue is (or ensure your wallet is fully synced if you are using a local wallet).

> I figured that when the amount will reach Shapeshift, they will issue an automatic refund although the blockchair says that the main part of the deposit is already sent and spent.

Why would you get a refund if you are just depositing the funds?

> I tried to use CPFP while it was still unconfirmed to draft the funds back, but it seems like I misunderstood the function.

If you sent the funds to an address shapeshift owns, only they can spend that transaction, so only they can use CPFP. But CPFP is unnecessary here because the transaction is confirmed now, as you mentioned.

> Can anybody tell me what's the problem, if it's stuck for centuries or how to speed it up? And it is actually a second time in a row I get into this situation. Anyway, would anybody just sort out my confusion?

What makes you think it is stuck? The transaction was successful, if your account hasn't been credited in shapeshift then you will need to contact their support.

Comment: I guess I didn't make clear what happened: the time for the deposit on an exchange operation expired before the funds from my side got to the address. Thanks a lot though. I downloaded the newest version of the electron cash and it all shows up there. They actually made the refund 2 hours after the failure to deposit.

Comment: @Sokol66 glad to hear :) If the problem is resolved it would be great if you could mark the question as answered btw